# How to fill value of on textbox based on value of other in ms-access in continuous forms for each record

Tags: vba, ms-access, lookup-tables, continuous-forms

I have a continuous form which is filled by a table. Now when a user wants to edit a textbox on the form I want to populate another textbox on the same form. This would happen on the exit event of the firts text box.

Please suggest options, can I use dlookup or use vba to iterate through recordset and then fill corresponding record textbox. Share a code snippet can I use to find which record textbox is edited an fill corresponding one.

Comment: Why do you want to use other textboxes? The users should be able to edit the original ones on your form? Yes, you could use VBA to iterate through the controls on the form or the records in the underlying recordset. But I don't understand how this will be useful.

Comment: Its a kind of lookup value, i.e if user enters a in textbox 1 the textbox2 and textbox 3 should get values from a table based upon value entered in textbox 1. This needs to be true for all recods present in the continuous form.

Comment: Would you be able to post a screenshot? This doesn't sound like a common UI design.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, first textbox 1 and take one command button
write one macro which contian logic of fill textbox on click command button and Fill value of corresponding textboxs value base on textbox1 value

Comment: I did something of the same sort. Thanks for reply.